# Accessing models from within the lib directory in a Rails 3 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a file in the lib directory that uses some constants defined in a model, like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   MAX_EMAIL_ADDRESS_LENGTH = 255
end
```

and then I have in lib/foo.rb

```
module Foo
  LONG_EMAIL_ADDRESS = "foo@bar.com".rjust(User::MAX_EMAIL_ADDRESS_LENGTH, "a")
end
```

It fails due to not finding the class User. How can I load User before that file on lib?

I'm loading that file by having this in my application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Comment: How are you including `lib` in your rails application? In rails 3 it's not auto-loaded by default, so showing how you're gaining access to `lib/foo.rb` would be helpful.

Comment: Do you have this module included? If so, where it is included?

Comment: @denis.peplin, no I'm not requiring and if I require it, I get an error that the file can't be found.

Comment: Do not require, `include` it. Please look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was, that my file in /lib was actually being required by a rake file, and it seems rake files are loaded before the whole auto-load system is setup by Rails, so it couldn't find the model. After I remove the require from the .rake file, everything started working.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a old question but I've just faced the same problem and after some searches, I found a solution so I think it worth to share it.

I wanted to use a model "Foo" in one required files located in my /lib directory. First, I did this and it didn't work :

```
# in my rake file
task :foo_task do
  require /some_path/lib/bar.rb
end

# in /lib/bar.rb
puts "Foo = #{Foo.count} "

# => uninitialized constant Foo
```

After some searches, I found that to access models in my lib's files, I need to specify the environment in my task. So I just added this to my task declaration :

```
task :foo_task => [:environment] do
```

Now, when I call my task, it correctly puts the number of Foo :

```
# => Foo = 6
```

Answer (score 3):

The first part was done right:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Next, it is important, module

```
module Foo
  ...
end
```

must be placed into

```
lib/foo.rb
```

file.

And then, it can be `include`d into application code.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Foo
  ...
end
```

If file `foo.rb` from lib directory is not intended to be included (however it is probably a wrong way), then to use Rails models and other stuff inside this code you should put this into foo.rb:

```
require_relative "../config/environment.rb"
```

Comment: I am not trying to access a lib from from a model, but a model from a lib file.

Comment: So try `require_relative "../config/environment.rb"`

Answer (score 1):

By default, `YourApplicationNameHere::Application.autoload_paths` is `[]`. I *(purely for organizational reasons)* add a glob for my `app/models` directory too.

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/**/"]
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib"]
```

With this setup I'm able to do what you're asking in the Question without trouble. This should benefit you as well, telling Rails where to look if it can't find the `User` model from within your `lib/` module's instantiation.

**Edit**

Specifying the exact error message in your question would have helped too.

```
uninitialized constant Foo::User
```

means Ruby/Rails is looking for `User` within the `Foo` namespace. Prefix `User` with `::` to force the lookup to the global namespace.

```
module Foo
  LONG_EMAIL_ADDRESS = "foo@bar.com".rjust(::User::MAX_EMAIL_ADDRESS_LENGTH, "a")
end
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. I tried several variations and I always end up with: uninitialized constant Foo::User.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your class User has not be instantiated, which seems unusual, unless you have 'user.rb' in a location other than 'models'.  It is often the case that classes aren't loaded in development unless they are specifically in that directory, but one solution I use is this line that you could put just within your code that you expect to be called prior to the offending line you have..

```
Rails.application.eager_load! if Rails.env == "development"
```

The conditional part is probably unnecessary, but I include it just to be certain its effect only occurs in development.