# Using ActiveRecord models from lib directory in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, sinatra

How can I access models from a class in lib directory in rails application? I'm currently getting a `uninitialized constant ClassName::ModelName` when trying to access models. The error occurs when I try to run migrations(I'm transferring a Sinatra app to Rails)

The model is in `app/models/parsed_company.rb`

```
class ParsedCompany < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

The class in lib directory is defined as follows

```
class DefaultMergeStrategy
  COMPANY_ATTRIBUTES = (ParsedCompany.column_names.map(&:to_sym) - [:created_at, :updated_at])
end
```

Comment: If this is a model that inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base` then is should live in `app/models/[model_name].rb`. Can we get some of the code that you're using so we can have some context?

Comment: @Kyle Decot
I've added some details. The model is in app/models directory

Comment: It sounds like you want to ParsedCompany to inherit the attributes from your lib directory correct?

Comment: @David
Actually I want to access my models from within lib directory

Comment: Please see the following SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632065/accessing-models-from-within-the-lib-directory-in-a-rails-3-project I am certain of it this should help you