# Creating models from lib directory in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a file lib/stock_reader.rb in which I'm trying to create a model like so:

```ruby
module StockReader
  def self.create_company_reports(company_data)
    CompanyReport.create(name: company[:name])
  end
end
```

In another file, lib/curate.rb, I call this method:

```
require_relative 'stock_reader'

StockReader.create_company_reports(company_data)
```

But I receive the error:

```
/Users/me/code/applications/curator/lib/stock_reader.rb:38:in `block in create_company_reports': uninitialized constant StockReader::CompanyReport (NameError)
from /Users/me/code/applications/curator/lib/stock_reader.rb:37:in `each'
from /Users/me/code/applications/curator/lib/stock_reader.rb:37:in `create_company_reports'
from lib/curate.rb:12:in `<main>'
```

It seems that my lib directory is failing to recognize my model's existence in app/models/company_report.rb:

```
class CompanyReport < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I'm guessing this may be because the lib/ directory is being loaded before app/models, but I'm not sure.

I've looked at [Accessing models from within the lib directory in a Rails 3 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632065/accessing-models-from-within-the-lib-directory-in-a-rails-3-project) but I can't see where my lib/ directory is being required in any rakefiles.

Comment: When do you intend for the `CompanyReport.create` line to run?

Comment: @Jordan I have another file in lib/ in which I call methods from StockReader containing the CompanyReport.create. I include the StockReader module in that file using `require_relative 'stock_reader'`

Comment: You haven't defined any methods in StockReader...

Comment: @Jordan I left the methods out for brevity's sake

Comment: That would be fine, except the code you posted has completely different semantics from a module with a method in it, and doesn't tell us what we need to know about the context in which you're attempting to access `CompanyReport`. Please post your actual code.

Comment: We also need to know when the error is occurring, and seeing the backtrace would be helpful.

Comment: @Jordan I've edited my question to be more specific and included some more code.

Comment: When is this happening?

Comment: It happens when I test lib/curate.rb by running $ ruby lib/curate.rb. And now I feel dumb - Do I need to start the server first I suppose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It happens when I test `lib/curate.rb` by running `$ ruby lib/curate.rb`

Well, that would explain it.

Ruby doesn't know anything about CompanyReport. Rails knows where to find your models because it has a ton of code that handles autoloading classes, but Ruby isn't Rails. If you want code to use Rails' features, you need to run the code in the "Rails environment."

There are a few ways to do this. If you want to run an arbitrary script (like `lib/curate.rb`) in the Rails environment, you can use the `rails runner` command:

```
$ bin/rails runner lib/curate.rb
```

The Rails console is also very useful for testing:

```
$ bin/rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.6)
irb(main):001:0> require Rails.root + "lib/curate"
```

It's pretty rare to use the `ruby` command in a Rails project, because usually you want to use Rails' features. You'll probably use the above commands a lot more often.

Comment: This works great - was not aware of the `rails runner`. When you asked 'When is this happening?', I realized how dumb I was being. But very cool to see that you can load the environment using runner. Thanks very much Jordan. Would upvote if I had the rep :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `CompanyReport` class does not exist in the `StockReader` module where it's looking for it.  To use the top level `CompanyReport` model preface the class name with `::`

```
::CompanyReport.create(name: company[:name])
```